# Парсинг текста HTML с помощью jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Нужно вытащить текст *"Количество помещений (зданий) - всего, единиц"* по `id` (так как далее номера `id` будут перебираться в цикле).

Пытаюсь так: `.select("#td_1188591077").text()`, но ничего не находит.

```
<tr>
    <td class="corner">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="td_1188591077" class="graph" style="width: 90px;">
        [2]
        <span class="gn">Количество помещений (зданий) - всего, единиц &#160; &#160;</span>
        <img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="90" height="1" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td id="td_1188592077" class="graph" style="width: 90px;">
        [3]
        <span class="gn">из них число памятников истории и культуры федерального значения</span>
        <img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="90" height="1" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td id="td_1188593077" class="graph" style="width: 90px;">
        [4]
        <span class="gn">из них число памятников истории и культуры регионального значения</span>
        <img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="90" height="1" alt="" />
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.select` вообще непонятно. откуда это?

`$('#td_1188591077 .gn').text();`

либо в цикле

```
$('.graph').each(function(){
    gntext = $('.gn',this).text();
    console.log(gntext);
});
```

Comment: использовал .select таким образом 
String linkText = document1.select("a[href*=javascript: OpenPart("1188589077")]").first().text();
забирал из такой строки 

'<a href="javascript: OpenPart(1188589077)" class="part">Раздел 1</a><br />'

Comment: А почему бы второй вариант не сделать как `$('.graph .gn').each(function() { gntext = $(this).text();  console.log(gntext); });`? Несколько короче и каждый элемент `.gn` обрабатывается отдельно.

Comment: я только начинающий кодер, и как понимаю $ не относиться к java?

Comment: оооооууууу, простите! я вроде указывал java + html + jsoup, но он выставил вообще другое:( еще раз простите

Comment: @like.the.other хотя это я уже не прав. Забыл, что jsoup - это библиотека для Java.

Comment: @xaja в общем, мы приходим к тому, что этот ответ не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @Regent все равно спасибо, начал "работать" а спросить не у кого, иногда над простыми задачами часами бьюсь

Answer (score 1):

Для jsoup есть песочница. Тестируйте html и селекторы сначала там, если сразу не выходит: http://try.jsoup.org/~BxwE3t2luCJ6PnUJOAgkRyNAMNE

В частности ваш кусок html (без table) он парсит не так как хотелось бы.